# Nginx custom config file setting doesn't work when firing up the server

Tags: nginx, cmd, vbscript, config, nginx-config

I am trying to configure the Nginx, PHP on Windows 7 64Bit, such that both PHP & Nginx should always use the path that I have specified to them during startup or in the config files.

Now as for Nginx, I am starting it's server executable with the following VBScript for custom config file loading:

```
... Vbs code ...
sh.run "cmd /K CD "& NginxPath &" & start nginx", 0
sh.run "cmd /K CD "& NginxPath &" & start nginx -c "& NginxConf, 0
sh.run "cmd /K CD "& NginxPath &" & start nginx -s reload", 0
... Vbs code ...
```

But it always throws the same error consistently:

```
2019/01/21 06:53:52 [emerg] 6988#5196: CreateFile() "Custom\Path\mime.types" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified) in Custom\Path\nginx.conf:18
```

And even with this error the Server starts but loads the default config file, which shouldn't happen at all.

BTW, the variables NginxPath & NginxConf both have correct Windows Path with proper double-quoting(eg. "C:\path\file.conf")

Even if we forget about VBscript, and simply fire below command in CMD, it gives same error:

```
nginx -c C:\custom\path\nginx.conf
```

Error

```
nginx: [emerg] CreateFile() "C:\custom\path\mime.types" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified) in C:\custom\path\nginx.conf:18
```

So why is this happening and how to resolve it with using custom conf file as I desire ?

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), because it is about a program configuration problem, not about a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere in your custom nginx config file exists following line:

```
include       mime.types;
```

Try to add full path to this file (which is located in the same folder where default config file is) to this `include` directive:

```
include       C:/path/to/default/config/mime.types;
```

As alternative, you can place a copy of `mime.types` file to the same folder where your custom config file is located.

Comment: Yes as first step of issue resolving trial, I did this, but then turn-by-turn it asks for every file of that folder, so please let me know once-in-for-all solution, that would really help. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know how to do this, maybe you could change current directiry in your script to default nginx config one and then nginx will look for every included file in the current dir? (not sure about this, but it worth a try)